# Java maths, working out total combinations

Tags: java, math, recursion, combinations

What's the easiest way I'd work out the total possible combinations of a method? Here is an example class of what I'm trying to work out;

```
class Combinations {

    public void generate()
    {
        final int TOTAL_A = 10;
        final int TOTAL_B = 21; // TOTAL_B is used twice
        final int TOTAL_C = 17;
        final int TOTAL_Z = 20;
        int count = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < TOTAL_A; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < TOTAL_B; b++)
            {
                for (int b_two = 0; b_two < TOTAL_B; b_two++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < TOTAL_C; c++)
                    {
                        for (int one = 0; one < TOTAL_Z; one++)
                            for (int two = one + 1; two < TOTAL_Z; two++)
                                for (int three = two + 1; three < TOTAL_Z; three++)
                                    for (int four = three + 1; four < TOTAL_Z; four++)
                                        for (int five = four + 1; five < TOTAL_Z; five++)
                                            count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total combinations: " + count);
    }

}
```

What would be the way to figure out what "count" would be without having to actually do the loops?

Comment: Why don't you explain, in words, what it is exactly that you're trying to count?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a puzzle combination which requires 4 unique objects from the first 4 loops, the second object has the same resource size as the third. After this I have to choose 5 other objects that are unique, as in, they can't have the same object. Which is where the + 1 from the last number comes in.

Comment: A better explanation, if possible? Anyway, you are doing 8 nested for loops, that's probably wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how many distinct combination exist given the counts A, B1, B2, C and Z, where B1 and B2 are the same size?

Comment: Please take some time to revise your question and better explain what you want to do. As the question currently stands, it is highly unclear, even with your attempt to clarify in the comments.

Comment: @phant0m, if you look at the code I'm finding how many combinations there are available by simply adding 1 to count. What I'm trying to find out is that number without having to actually do the loops. I'm pretty sure it's possible with doing some maths.

Comment: It seems quite complicated, still, you can add this line `count*=TOTAL_A * TOTAL_B * TOTAL_B * TOTAL_C` instead of the 4 first loops, right after the last calculations

Comment: Just to make sure this is your desired result. Your loop instantiates: one = 0, two = 1, three = 2, four = 3, five = 4 in the beginning, but since you used variables, when it's looped through the bottom loop, five is set equal to four + 1 even when four is approaching TOTAL_Z. That effect trinkles all the way up through the for loops. Is that what you are trying to have happen?

Comment: Yes @AndrewCampbell, That's to make it so that the last part is permutational, so that none of the results from those parts will equal the same.

Comment: I am definitely not a mathematician. So, this certainly isn't my type problem, but I thought permutation is accomplished with @I.G. Pascual's answer of n factorial (n!). I might be making myself look foolish (if so, I will delete and leave this problem to the pros) ,but when the `one` variable is equal to 16 is 'count++' even reached?

Comment: Your question is not in the code. The code is not what you want to do, it's a flawed solution. To help with your problem, it's easier if you explain what you want.

Comment: @phant0m Such a radical change to a question without a clear statement from the OP is inappropriate. I have rolled back.

Comment: @DanielFischer I noticed. However, "my version" of the question would have made it clear what was asked, with only one doubt as pointed out by Perception.

Comment: @phant0m **If** that was what was asked. Without the OP clarifying, we can't know whether the OP wants what he wrote or what you thought he asked.

Comment: @DanielFischer He basically [**stated it in a comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919310/java-maths-working-out-total-combinations#comment19186663_13919310). Why do you think "what he asked" is so different from what I rephrased it to?

Comment: @phant0m I don't find that comment clear at all. It may mean what you think it means, in which case the OP should roll back to your version. But it could also be that the OP is trying to put into words what his loops do. I'll leave it to the OP to judge, nobody else can know what was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
|A| * (|B| choose 2) * |C| * (|Z| choose 5) = 553,492,800
```

Or if you want to choose from two different pools `B1` and `B2` that have the same size:

```
|A| * |B1| * |B2| * |C| * (|Z| choose 5) = 1,162,334,880
```

where `n choose k` is defined as follows:

```
n!/(k!*(n-k)!)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and have looked more in-depth into permutation combinations and have found the same array as shown. However, I haven't figured out a way to translate that type of algorithm into Java code, so I will keep this question open for now. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, found an Apache library which has a method for calculating this, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The outer loops, `a, b, b_two, c` do not influence what is done in the inner loops at all, so they just produce a factor of repetitions,

```
TOTAL_A * TOTAL_B² * TOTAL_C
```

that you multiply with the work of the inner loops.

The inner loops, `one, two, three, four, five` influence or depend on other loops. Each loop determines the range of the enclosed loop, so you'd naturally work inside out.

```
for (int five = four + 1; five < TOTAL_Z; five++)
     count++;
```

So the innermost loops increments `count` a total of `TOTAL_Z - 1 - four` times. Let us denote `TOTAL_Z - 1` by `N` for brevity.

the `four` loop does

```
N - four
```

increments for `four` ranging from `three+1` to `N`,

```
    N             N-three-1
    ∑ (N - four) =    ∑ k    = (N-three)*(N-three-1)/2
four=three+1         k=0
```

The `three` loop does `(N-three)*(N-three-1)/2` increments for `three` ranging from `two+1` to `N`. Setting `j = N - three`, that gives

```
N-two-1
  ∑    j*(j-1)/2 = (N-two)*(N-two-1)*(N-two-2)/6
 j=0
```

The `two` loop does `(N-two)*(N-two-1)*(N-two-2)/6` increments for `two` ranging from `one+1` to `N`, setting `j = N - two`, that gives

```
N-one-1
   ∑   j*(j-1)*(j-2)/6 = (N-one)*(N-one-1)*(N-one-2)*(N-one-3)/24
  j=0
```

and finally, the `one` loop does the above amount of increments for `one` ranging from 0 to `N`, giving

```
   N                                            N
   ∑ (N-one)*(N-one-1)*(N-one-2)*(N-one-3)/24 = ∑ k*(k-1)*(k-2)*(k-3)/24
one=0                                          k=0
                                              =  (N+1)*N*(N-1)*(N-2)*(N-3)/120
```

(or `` (N+1) `choose` 5 ``) increments in the inner loops together.

`N = TOTAL_Z - 1 = 19`, `` 20 `choose` 5 = 15504 ``, multiplying with the constants of the outer loops gives 1162334880 increments of `count` in total.

The crucial fact that allows a simple computation here is that

```
 m
 ∑   (n+k) `choose` k = (n+m+1) `choose` m
k=0
```